# LibGDX with AndroidX (i need Fragments and WorkManager)

Tags: android, libgdx, androidx

I am asking the `LibGDX` community, based on this information: https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6096

**Please, is it possible to use LibGDX with AndroidX Fragments?**

**Can You start using AndroidX in future versions of LibGDX?**

I am using `"com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication"`, which is using old "android.support.v4.app.Fragment". And it is incompatible with any AndroidX because of duplicate core classes.

And I was also using BroadcastReceiver and JobService for repeated tasks. But Android 9 and his new battery power management is killing my app. Or even won't start them. 
Google is pushing to use new WorkManager, that should solve all problems with battery management. But it is using only AndroidX.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

What I understand, it is only about changing Artifact Mappings path to package? 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings 
I already migrated all from my project, but I cannot change LibGDX.

Thank You.
Best Regards.
Petr Vyhnalek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libgdx has update for androidx library:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libgdx/libgdx/master/CHANGES

You can update your libgdx dependency with version 1.9.11 or later and it is OK.

```
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.11"
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.11"
```